# How to copy a single visible cell?

Tags: excel, vba

This code is supposed to copy one visible cell only - Cells(11,4) for example. However, it is copying all visible cells in the worksheet.

```
Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Cells(11, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: IIRC special cells with one cell only selects all such cells so you need to check the count first. Why not just check if that row/column is visible?

Comment: I'm a beginner at vba. Would you please give me further explanation or a sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
Sub x()

With Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Cells(11, 4)
    If Not (.EntireRow.Hidden Or .EntireColumn.Hidden) Then .Copy
End With

End Sub
```